# SEO for Ajax pagination for reviews on a product page?

Tags: php, ajax, magento, pagination, seo

I have a Magento site where my product pages load customer reviews through ajax pagination. Each ajax link loads 10 reviews and replaces the 10 previous ones. There is no url change or page refresh, just a simple content replacement. I also don't have a no-javascript fall back because Magento literally cannot function without it so it's a moot point.

I have researched ways to let search engines know to index this content, but all I can find is methods for full page indexing using Google's rel="prev/next/canonical" methods: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/09/pagination-with-relnext-and-relprev.html and http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/09/view-all-in-search-results.html.

These solutions don't seem to be relevant in my case because I'm not paginating the whole product page, but instead a portion of it. Using these methods search engines would see the product information (descriptions, titles, specs) on every page (product.html?reviewpage=2, for example) and flag for duplicate content. The view all solution would be far too cumbersome with as many reviews as we are getting.

Should I reconsider the way I'm displaying reviews? Can I direct search engines to a separate reviews page?

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If SEO is a top priority for you than you should consider showing the reviews as part of the page. The way I would go about it is show all the reviews on the page (say up to 1000) and than apply some smart JavaScript code to emulate pagination on these reviews.

Bottom line is AJAX bypasses SEO. No matter how smart Google Bots are getting lately, traditional content that lives on the page will win the SEO game since you will have so much more control on how to display it and how the user engages with the content.

Comment: We decided for our purposes to link products to a separate non-ajax paginated reviews section. A 'view all reviews' section, much like how Amazon does it. This gives us the opportunity to add rating filters and such later without cluttering up our product page. This is a good solution, however, so I'll accept it as the correct one. thanks!